# Better option for small files, send or compress and send?

Tags: c#, performance, compression

If I have relative small file (<1 Mb) what is better option for program, first compress file to the disk , and than send this .zip file , or send only. I am never sure for net and disk speed, file size is changing to ,but that is not big changes . I think that compress, of course, is better for larger file, but when file is few Kb are I getting something with compressing of it , or I lose because time that i need to write and read from hdd?

Thanx

Comment: I think the size of file after compression is probably going to be negligible for files that size. Where exactly is your bottleneck?

Comment: It depends upon type of the file. For instance simple txt files and xml files are highly compressible where as executables and video files are not

Comment: What is the possible compression ratio? If it is noticeable (5:1...?), I would start to think about compression.

Comment: Compression ratio if it's an XML of a dataset as an example compression will be varying between 7:1 to about 30:1. So it depends on the file format. for an XML again the compression ratio will be higher the more records you have. See id you have only 1 record the ratio is roughly 2:1 but if you have 1.5 million records you can have in the 30:1 ratio. You should try a quick compression test with something like [SharpZipLib](http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/)

Comment: There are also specialized compression algorithms for very fast compression and decompression - at the cost of lower compression ratio, e.g. https://lz4net.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Are you sending via HTTP to a web browser, or is this a special-purpose client-server interaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to read the file from disk, compress it, and then send it without re-writing the compressed file to disk.  The receiver can then decompress it in memory.  This is essentially how a web server serves compressed web pages to compatible browsers.

C# is not a language I'm familiar with, but you are probably looking for something like System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.